# Using the anonymous mysql account on RoR

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I know that for a safe database there needs to be a username and a password. However, I was curious as why ruby on rails does not allow you to use an anonymous account on mysql. I have tried keeping the username and password lines empty in the database.yml

May be I am not understanding exactly where the database information is stored on a RoR application. I have also tried to go to the mysql2 directory under "Ruby192\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\mysql2-0.2.6-x86-mingw32" (this is the version i am using just to let u guys know). But I dont really know where to look.

If anyone has any ideas, or an explanation as whether ruby even allows u to access the database without a username and a password.

Comment: You can have a blank password in MySQL, but no blank user.

Answer (score 0):

What error are you seeing?

Password definitely is not required in the config, but if I try setting the username to blank, and inspect ActiveRecord::Base.connection in the console, I can see it's defaulted back to using root.

Comment: That makes sense, when I leave the username blank I see the following error. Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO). So basically how can I prevent the username from being defaulted back to using root?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of the rationale (well, in terms of security I understand why it's frowned on, but not why it's forced), but it's a hardcoded fallback on [line 36 of active record's mysql adapter](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb#L36)